# Find and disable unnecessary services in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, optimization

I have been presented with a server running `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` server edition.

This machine was in use earlier for a web application and also has many other applications configured in it. Now, I want to remove all the un necessary applications from it like apache2 etc. and do a fresh start for installation of the new application.

Now, the problem is how can I determine what applications i.e. packages are installed in it, and how can I disable/uninstall and optimize this server.

After uninstalling the packages I want to optimize it to disable Packages for Securing it much like point number 3 in the link [here.](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-server-hardening-security-tips/)

But it's not for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use rcconf to disable some (not all) services:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
sudo rcconf
```

For other services (depending if they use init or upstart) I use bum (Boot Up Manager):

```
sudo apt-get install bum
gksu  bum
```

Note that this second one requires a GUI. If someone can point out a terminal equivalent it'll help you. You can also use the service command to start, stop, restart or configure daemons (services):

```
sudo service <nameoftheservice> <options>
man service # To get a manual about how to use it.
```

Comment: Great rcconf is the thing I was looking for. One more thing I got your point that bum need GUI. But can you please explain the difference between `rcconf` and `bum`. Doesn't rcconf lists all startup applications?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but for what a read some time ago, some services use init while some others use upstart. Both are different system and so the services are controlled with different commands and programs. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I'm sure somebody else will be able to expand the subject.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for the help. rcconf is the right solution for me as I don't have a GUI. :)